# List of all colors in an image using opencv and python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

Python beginner here. I'm using python 3.6 and opencv and I'm trying to create a list of rgb values of all colors present in an image. I can read the rgb values of one pixel using cv2.imread followed by image[px,px]. The result is a numpy array. What I want is list of rgb tuples of unique colors present in an image and am not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Have you tried the naive aproach of just looping over the whole image and collecting every unique color (i.e. keep a list/dict/whatever with every color seen so far)

Comment: I wasn't sure how to convert from array to tuple and I just searched and apparantly tuple(a) where a is array gives tuple lol (forgive me, I just started learning python). So, I'm trying the looping approach now. Meanwhile, it'd be great if someone could share a better approach since I have to loop it over 3000 images and it may take a long time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out numpy's [numpy.unique()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([[255,233,200], [23,66,122], [0,0,123], [233,200,255], [23,66,122]])
print(np.unique(test, axis=0, return_counts = True))

>>> (array([[  0,   0, 123],
       [ 23,  66, 122],
       [233, 200, 255],
       [255, 233, 200]]), array([1, 2, 1, 1]))
```

You can collect the RGB numpy arrays in a 2D numpy array and then use the numpy.unique() funtion with the `axis=0` parameter to traverse the arrays within. Optional parameter `return_counts=True` will also give you the number of occurences.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I still had to loop over whole image and over many images to get the arrays and then used np.unique.

Comment: @KalyanM That should not be necessary. I have not validated it but the following should work as the cv2.imread() function already returns a numpy ndarray:
`img = cv2.imread(path_to_img)` to get the 3D ndarray of per pixel rbgs.
`all_rgb_codes = img.reshape(-1, img.shape[-1])` to flatten the 3D array by one dimension to a 2D array we need.
`unique_rgbs = np.unique(all_rgb_codes, axis=0)` to get the unique colors as per my answer above.
Please test and evaluate this tho before using it in production. 
Happy coding :)